# When importing Mixamo animated characters into Unity, they come without avatar?

Tags: unity, animation, fbx, rigging, animator

I'm using Unity 2019.3.3f1. I create the character in Adobe Fuse. I uploaded it to Mixamo and choose an animation. I then downloaded the fbx for unity file. When imported into Unity, it is visible that the file has no avatar or animator component. How can I fix this? Is it a Unity version issue?

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this problem as well but since no one actually answered the question I'll say what I did to solve it. You are correct that it seems to be a version issue, I fixed it by simply making a new project in an older version (2018.4.7f1 specifically), and then I dragged the fbx file into the project. Once I imported it, I then exported it as a unity package file, and then imported it into the 2019 project file. This gave me the model with the animator component.